# SDL_RenderPresent() not working

Tags: c, sdl, c99, sdl-2

I am trying to draw a grid in a window using sdl2. The program when it is run, sometimes, the `SDL_RenderPresent()` even though being called, is not working resulting in a blank transparent window. Other times, the program is giving the correct output.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

const SDL_Color BLACK = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color WHITE = { .r = 255, .g = 255, .b = 255, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color GRAY = { .r = 128, .g = 128, .b = 128, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color RED = { .r = 255, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color MAROON =  { .r = 128, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color BLUE = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 255, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color NAVY = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 128, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color LIME = { .r = 0, .g = 255, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color GREEN = { .r = 0, .g = 128, .b = 0, .a = 255 };

const int P_SIZE = 10;

void draw_grid(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    SDL_Color prev;
    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev.a, &prev.g, &prev.b, &prev.a);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, GRAY.r, GRAY.g, GRAY.b, GRAY.a);
    // drawing the axes
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0,
            SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT); // the Y-axis
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2,
            SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2); // the X-axis

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, BLACK.r, BLACK.g, BLACK.b, BLACK.a);
    // drawing the grid
    for (int i = 0; i <= SCREEN_WIDTH; i += P_SIZE) {
        if (i == SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) {
            continue;
        }
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, i, 0, i, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= SCREEN_HEIGHT; i += P_SIZE) {
        if (i == SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) {
            continue;
        }
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, i, SCREEN_WIDTH, i);
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, prev.a, prev.g, prev.b, prev.a);
}

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    SDL_Window *window =
        SDL_CreateWindow("Clipping",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
        );
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
            SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nRenderer could not be created:%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, WHITE.r, WHITE.g, WHITE.b, WHITE.a);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    draw_grid(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    int quit = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have event loop but not drawing in it. This is not how it supposed to be. Draw on each frame or at least react when window manager says your window needs to be redrawn.

Comment: This line: `for (int i = 0; i <= SCREEN_WIDTH; i += P_SIZE) {` will draw one pixel past the end of the visible window.  Such drawing is outside the bounds of the screen boundaries.  This is undefined behavior.  Suggest using: `for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH; i += P_SIZE) {`

Comment: @user3629249 SDL_Renderer is with GL/D3D here, it is safe to exceed screen space, clipping will be performed if necessary.